# Irreducibility in finite field implies irreducibility in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: galois-theory

Let $p$ be a prime, $f$ be a polynomial of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Suppose that $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

My question is : Is $f$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ?

This question is originally came from the example 4.29 from the notes Field and Galois theory of J.S.Milne, in that he gave an implication of " a polynomial is irreducibile mod 3(still reducible mod 2) then it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$.

**Update** I have more question after reading the comments and answer below. So, if $f$ is monic, what is the condition for irreducible mod $p$ for some prime $p$ implying irreducibility of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ? Must it be "irreducible modulo $p$ for all the prime $p$ (not for some) ?

Comment: Not true, as the counterexamples below show. But if the leading coefficient of $f$ is not divisible by $p$, then yes (because then the degrees of any factors are preserved upon reduction modulo $p$).

Answer (score 13):

To elaborate on Ted's comment, if the leading coefficient is not zero in the finite field, then this actually is true. The easiest way to see why is to consider the *contrapositive*:

$~\bf($irreducible in $\Bbb F_p[x]\implies$ irreducible in $\Bbb Z[x]\bf)\iff ($reducible in $\Bbb Z[x]\implies$ reducible in $\Bbb F_p[x]\bf)$

If $f(x)=a(x)b(x)$ is true in $\Bbb Z[x]$ then it is true in $\Bbb F_q[x]$; the only obstacle to the latter implication then is if one of the $a(x)$ or $b(x)$ is a scalar after reducing modulo $p$, which can't happen if the degree of $f$ is preserved by the modulo reduction.

Comment: So, if a polynomial $f$ is irreducible mod $p$ for some prime $p$, and reducible mod $q$ for some other prime $q$, we can not say about the irreducibility of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, right ? I still have troubles with Milne's example.

Answer (score 6):

Certainly not. For example $x+px^2$ is irreducible mod $p$, as it is equivalent to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at $3x^2-x-2$ with $p=3$.